# WPF multiline textbox doesn't rendered as multiline inside usercontrol

Tags: wpf, textbox, user-controls, multiline

Inside `UserControl`, I add a `TextBox` as below

in xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="****"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
<UserControl.Resources>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=PromotionDetailsGroupBox, Path=Visibility}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="260"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="600"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <GroupBox Header="Settings" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="4">
                <Grid Margin="10 20 0 0">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Margin="18 0" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">Message</TextBlock>
                    <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Margin="10 0 4 4" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" Width="100" MaxLength="100" Height="60"></TextBox>
            </GroupBox>           
    </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

run the application, the `TextBox` always displays as a single line.

Can anybody tell me why?
thanks in advance.

Comment: "Can anybody tell me why?" Not without having seen the parent element(s) of the TextBox.

Comment: Your text box looks good. Now you should focus on your parent control. Can you add your parent control code?

Comment: @Clemens, thanks for your reply, code is updated.

Comment: So where is the text in your TextBox...? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I still didn't find out the root cause, I'm using the RichTextBox instead now.